# "deadline by which" vs. "deadline by when"

Tags: word-choice

Both the following seem legit to me:

- Is there a deadline by which I must submit my application?
- Is there a deadline by when I must submit my application?

Is one to be preferred over the other? Are there any particular situations where only one of them would fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though' ... deadline by when ...' is not unknown, it is far less idiomatic than '... deadline by which ...', as indicated by [these Google 3-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deadline+by+when%2Cdeadline+by+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeadline%20by%20when%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeadline%20by%20which%3B%2Cc0).

This is supported by the ratio of Google hits for the strings  "deadline by when" : "deadline by which" :: 30 000 : 1 100 000.

Though 'by when' (temporal) might seem more logical, as usual, usage trumps logic. Perhaps the notion of a non-temporal physical line in the early usage of the term is the reason.

Comment: Also note that according to Google Ngrams, *for when* is ten times as common as *by when* in general, and *deadline for when* has recently become an established phrase, rapidly expanding from zero to commonplace in the last 40 years.

Comment: I also found several interesting examples where *deadline by which* simply won't work  due to what follows. "... Finally, the Government would set a deadline by when the Boundary Commission for Wales should report its recommendations ..."  This leads to a nasty garden-path situation with *by which*. So there does seem to be a real usage issue buried in the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to COCA,Google Books and Hyper Collocation, "deadline by which" is correct while example sentences containing "deadline by when"from the three sources are simply unavailable. [image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 0):

**Deadline by which** is correct.

"by which" is the normal way of inverting an active sentence to make the passive voice.

> I live in that house.
>
> That is the house in which I live.

We do not say "That is the house in where I live."

So

> You must submit the work by this deadline.
>
> This is the deadline by which you must submit the work.

You can say "This is the house where I live" and so also "This is the deadline when you must submit the work.

Comment: But note @Phil Sweet's examples where 'deadline by which' doesn't sound natural.